# Traversing through indented arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion, nested

I have a javascript object as follows :

```
let hogwartsHeirarchy = {
  Headmaster: [
    {
      name: "Professor Dumbledore",
      key: 1,
      Headmistress: [
        {
          name: "Minerva McGonagall",
          key: 2,
          StandByProfessor: [
            {
              name: "Rubeus Hagrid",
              subject: "Potions Master",
              key: 3,
              Professor: [
                { name: "Horace Slughorn", key: 4 },
                { name: "Severus Snape", key: 4 },
              ],
            },
            {
              name: "Alastor Moody",
              subject: "Defense Against the Dark Arts",
              key: 3,
              Professor: [
                { name: "Remus Lupin", key: 4 },
                { name: "Gilderoy Lockhart", key: 4 },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

I want to print/get each of the node value [headmaster, headmastress,..] and their corresponding child values. I tried various methods like looping through the array using a for loop, recurse etc, but unfortunately I am not able to get any value out of the nodes. Please help.

e.g : I used this :

```
printArray(hogwartsHeirarchy);

function printArray(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] instanceof Array){
            console.log("true: ");

            console.log("intermediate one : ",arr[i]);

            printArray(arr[i]);

        }else{
            console.log("final one : ",arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The values can be shown in this format:

```
Headmaster - name : Professor Dumbledore, key : 1
.
.
StandByProfessor - name : Robeus Hagrid, subject : Potion Master, key : 3
StandByProfessor - name : Alastor Moody, subject : Defence against the dark arts, key : 3
.
.
Professor - ...
Professor - ...
Professor - ...
Professor - ...
```

Comment: please add the wanted result. how does it look?

Comment: `hogwartsHeirarchy` is an object not an array. `length` isn't a property on an object, so it will return `undefined`, so no iterations are happening on your for loop.

Comment: @peineary .. I am new to javascript, please help to tranverse though this object/array anyhow.

Comment: @Nina .. I have edited my question, plz check.

Comment: why not use a data structure with same key for nesting objects isntead of unknown key names?

Comment: @nina .. I am just v new to javascript. how to make a meaningful / data structure/ data out of the schema posted above. Can you post and write the code to traverse through the same.

Comment: Is the field `key` actually a key or it level of a hierarchy?

Comment: @FFire , its the level of heirarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a [1j01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2624876/1j01) object model:

```js
const hogwartsHeirarchy =
{  name: "Professor Dumbledore", role: "Headmaster", key: 1,
    subordinates: [{ name: "Minerva McGonagall", role: "Headmistress", key: 2,
        subordinates: [
          { name: "Rubeus Hagrid", role: "StandByProfessor", subject: "Potions Master", key: 3,
            subordinates: [
              { name: "Horace Slughorn", key: 4, role: "Professor" },
              { name: "Severus Snape", key: 4, role: "Professor"  }]},
          { name: "Alastor Moody", role: "StandByProfessor", subject: "Defense Against the Dark Arts", key: 3,
            subordinates: [
              { name: "Remus Lupin", key: 4, role: "Professor" },
              { name: "Gilderoy Lockhart", key: 4, role: "Professor" }]}]}]};
  
  
const visitStaff = (staffMember) => {
  const iter = (obj) => {
    const { name, role, key, subordinates } = obj;
    const subject = obj.subject ? `, subject : ${obj.subject}` : '';
    const line = `${role} - name : ${name}${subject}, key : ${key}`;
    const sublines = (Array.isArray(subordinates)) ? subordinates.flatMap(iter) : [];
    return [line, ...sublines];
  }
  return iter(staffMember).join('\n');
}
console.log(visitStaff(hogwartsHeirarchy));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Many thanks @FFire, this looks like a complete solution! I am still very new to properties like flatmap etc in javascript. Are there any proper references/library in javascript that makes these tasks automatic ? Right now, we are manually parsing/looping through each of the nodes.

Comment: @RahulK, there are no external libraries, such as lodash, etc., only vanila JS

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest restructuring so that the subordinates are always accessed with the same key, and thus can be visited very simply. I also made it so every node is a person, there's no object at the top that isn't a person. I left the variable name, but it now refers to Dumbledore directly.

```
let hogwartsHeirarchy =
  {
    name: "Professor Dumbledore",
    role: "Headmaster",
    key: 1,
    subordinates: [
      {
        name: "Minerva McGonagall",
        role: "Headmistress",
        key: 2,
        subordinates: [
          {
            name: "Rubeus Hagrid",
            role: "StandByProfessor",
            subject: "Potions Master",
            key: 3,
            subordinates: [
              { name: "Horace Slughorn", key: 4, role: "Professor" },
              { name: "Severus Snape", key: 4, role: "Professor"  },
            ],
          },
          {
            name: "Alastor Moody",
            role: "StandByProfessor",
            subject: "Defense Against the Dark Arts",
            key: 3,
            subordinates: [
              { name: "Remus Lupin", key: 4, role: "Professor" },
              { name: "Gilderoy Lockhart", key: 4, role: "Professor" },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  };
function visitStaff(staffMember) {
    if (staffMember.subordinates) {
        for (const subordinate of staffMember.subordinates) {
            visitStaff(subordinate);
        }
    }
    console.log("Staff member:", staffMember);
}
visitStaff(hogwartsHeirarchy);
```

When setting up a data structure, it's important to think about how it will be accessed, and what are its defining parts. In this case, there are people, which are the nodes, and (subordinate) relationships, which are the edges of the graph.

In your original code, you had an object `{ Headmaster: [...] }` — what does it represent? is it a person? no; is it a relationship? kind of, but no. It defines something about Dumbledoor, that he's the Headmaster, but not who or what he's the Headmaster *of*. So it's really just describing the role/job title of Dumbledoor, so it makes more sense as a property of the person. It's redundant as an object.

It helps to align your objects so they all represent something. You should be able to describe what each object and array is.

Comment: @1jo1, many thanks for simplying the structure and the explanation. The nodes are more self-explanatory and in a properly readable format now.

Comment: Edit : @1jo1, just checked you provided a solution along with the explanations as well. Thank you. The cleanest solution amongst all.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove known keys from the object and get the type hierarchy then iterate the property and return the tupel of type, name, subject and key only if type exists.

```js
const
    getValues = (object, type) => [
        ...(type ? [`${type} - name : ${object.name}, ${object.subject ? `subject : ${object.subject}, ` : ''}key : ${object.key}`] : []),
        ...Object
            .keys(object)
            .filter(k => !['name', 'subject', 'key'].includes(k))
            .flatMap(k => object[k].flatMap(o => getValues(o, k)))
        ],
    hogwartsHierarchy = { Headmaster: [{ name: "Professor Dumbledore", key: 1, Headmistress: [{ name: "Minerva McGonagall", key: 2, StandByProfessor: [{ name: "Rubeus Hagrid", subject: "Potions Master", key: 3, Professor: [{ name: "Horace Slughorn", key: 4 }, { name: "Severus Snape", key: 4 }] }, { name: "Alastor Moody", subject: "Defense Against the Dark Arts", key: 3, Professor: [{ name: "Remus Lupin", key: 4 }, { name: "Gilderoy Lockhart", key: 4 }] }] }] }] };

console.log(getValues(hogwartsHierarchy));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Nina for the help. This code looks a bit complex and much advanced to my javascript understanding. Is it possible for you to show the data in the format as described in the question itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the data structure:

a) I assume that there will be only one array in each type of "title", and
b) that array will contain a list of objects of a similar structure as it's parent

It's possible ...

1. to use `for..of` in order to
2. iterate through each key on an object, and add them to a string. Because there are arrays that contains objects,
3. I can loop through them, and
4. do a recursive loop, by having the method calling itself.

```js
const hogwartsHierarchy = { Headmaster: [{ name: "Professor Dumbledore", key: 1, Headmistress: [{ name: "Minerva McGonagall", key: 2, StandByProfessor: [{ name: "Rubeus Hagrid", subject: "Potions Master", key: 3, Professor: [{ name: "Horace Slughorn", key: 4 }, { name: "Severus Snape", key: 4 }] }, { name: "Alastor Moody", subject: "Defense Against the Dark Arts", key: 3, Professor: [{ name: "Remus Lupin", key: 4 }, { name: "Gilderoy Lockhart", key: 4 }] }] }] }] };

function printAllWithChilds(obj, prevProp) {
  let listItem = (prevProp) ? ' -- ' + prevProp : '';
  
  for (const property in obj) {    // 1
    if (obj[property] instanceof Array) {
       obj[property].forEach((child_obj) => {                   // 3
         listItem += printAllWithChilds(child_obj, property);   // 4
       });
    } else {
      listItem += `, ${property}: ${obj[property]}`;            // 2
    }
  }
  
  return listItem;
}

let listStr = printAllWithChilds(hogwartsHierarchy);
console.log(listStr);
```

I would honestly split up `hogwartsHierarchy` into smaller bits, following a kind of database structure, where `primary_key` is unique for each individual. These arrays doesn't make much sense, until you look at the variable `professors` and how their respectively `belongs_to` key corresponds to the `standbyprofessors`, where you can see that "Horace Slughorn" belongs to "Rubeus Hagrid".

```
const headermaster = {
  name: "Professor Dumbledore",
  primary_key: 1
};

const headmistress = {
  name: "Minerva McGonagall",
  primary_key: 2,
  belongs_to: 1
};

const standbyprofessors = [{
    name: "Rubeus Hagrid",
    subject: "Potions Master",
    primary_key: 3,
    belongs_to: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Alastor Moody",
    subject: "Defense Against the Dark Arts",
    primary_key: 4,
    belongs_to: 2
  }
];

const professors = [{
    name: "Horace Slughorn",
    primary_key: 5,
    belongs_to: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Severus Snape",
    primary_key: 6,
    belongs_to: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Remus Lupin",
    primary_key: 7,
    belongs_to: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Gilderoy Lockhart",
    primary_key: 8,
    belongs_to: 4
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks @Rickard for all the explanations and the solution. I would personally want to divide this large node based structure as explained by you, but, the client is providing us the data in that particular format only as described in the question.

I also tried initially parsing using the recursion method only, can we expect the recursion to be more performant than the methods discussed by FFire and Lina ?

Comment: FFire's code looks as efficient as mine, because my code only loops once. Nina's includes `keys, filter, includes and flatmap` (twice), which all are loops in themselves, which suggests less sufficient code.